# Desabilitar tab que mostra todos resultados

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Estou com problemas nesse codigo, pois quero cadastrar o case, porem quero remover a tab onde todos aparecem, quer que parte de cada selecionado!

A primeira tab, é mostrar todos (quero desabilitar), quero que comece direto do teste1, porem ele nao começa, sempre mostra todos

```js
//* Isotope js
    function protfolioIsotope(){
        if ( $('.portfolio').length ){ 
            // Activate isotope in container
            $(".portfolio_inner").imagesLoaded( function() {
                $(".portfolio_inner").isotope({
                    layoutMode: 'fitRows',  
                }); 
            }); 
            
            // Add isotope click function 
            $(".portfolio_filter li").on('click',function(){
                $(".portfolio_filter li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active"); 
    element.removeAttribute('data-filter');
                var selector = $(this).attr("data-filter");
                $(".portfolio_inner").isotope({
                    filter: selector,
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 450,
                        easing: "linear",
                        queue: false,
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }); 
             
            //*  Simple LightBox js 
            $('.imageGallery .light').simpleLightbox()
        };
    };
```

```css
@import 'https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import 'https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/css/font-awesome.min.css';
@import 'https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/css/style.css';
```

```html
<!-- jQuery v3.3.1 -->
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap v4.0.0 -->
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/vendors/parallaxmouse/parallax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/vendors/lightbox/simpleLightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/vendors/isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/vendors/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<section class="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 class="col-xl-3 tittle">Meus Trabalhos</h2>
      <ul class="portfolio_filter col-xl-9">
        <li class="active" data-filter="*"><a href="#">todos</a></li>
        <li data-filter=".teste1"><a href="#"> teste1</a></li>
        <li data-filter=".teste2"><a href="#">teste2</a></li>
        <li data-filter=".teste3"><a href="#">teste3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row portfolio_inner">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 graphic creative project teste1">
        teste 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 graphic creative project teste2">
        teste 2
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 graphic creative project teste3">
        teste 3
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Evandro vc poderia melhorar o texto da pergunta, dando mais detalhes e explicando melhor o que vc pretende. A forma como está escrito está meio confusa não da para entender muito bem o problema e o que vc quer...

Comment: tenho 5 nav-tabs, sendo que a primeira mostra todos os resultados, eu quero que ela nao apareça mais ex - todos |  cartões | folders | banners, quero tirar o todos

Comment: Por favor , melhore sua pergunta para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Pega a Aba Todos, coloca uma classe nela tipo class="todos" e no CSS coloca .todos{display:none} pronto vai sumir da tela

Comment: nao tem essa class, eu vou postar no servidor e passo o link pra vcs entenderem ok

Comment: https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/protfolio.html <- de uma olhada, e veja que quero remover o all

Comment: Você só quer tirar o "Todos" do isotope? mais nada??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você não quer a aba `todos`, simplesmente não a inclua no layout e ao carregar a página passe o filtro que deseja, no exemplo abaixo eu coloquei a class `.teste1`

E observe que você havia deixado no código as "tags" de exemplo (graphic creative project) elas são os marcadores do seu filtro, veja que eu adicionei a classe .teste2 no terceiro elemento, logo ele também vai aparecer na aba Teste 2, devido ao filtro.

```js
//* Isotope js
    function protfolioIsotope(){
        if ( $('.portfolio').length ){ 
            // Activate isotope in container
            $(".portfolio_inner").imagesLoaded( function() {
                $(".portfolio_inner").isotope({
                    filter: '.teste1',
                    layoutMode: 'fitRows',  
                    
                }); 
            }); 
            
            // Add isotope click function 
            $(".portfolio_filter li").on('click',function(){
                $(".portfolio_filter li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active"); 
                var selector = $(this).attr("data-filter");
                $(".portfolio_inner").isotope({
                    filter: selector,
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 450,
                        easing: "linear",
                        queue: false,
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }); 
             
            //*  Simple LightBox js 
            $('.imageGallery .light').simpleLightbox()
        };
    }; 
    
    //* Select js
    function selectmenu(){
        if ( $('.post_select').length ){ 
            $('select').niceSelect();
        };
    };  
       
    
    protfolioIsotope ();
```

```css
@import 'https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import 'https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/css/font-awesome.min.css';
@import 'https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/css/style.css';
```

```html
<!-- jQuery v3.3.1 -->
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap v4.0.0 -->
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/vendors/parallaxmouse/parallax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/vendors/lightbox/simpleLightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/vendors/isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/vendors/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<section class="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 class="col-xl-3 tittle">Meus Trabalhos</h2>
      <ul class="portfolio_filter col-xl-9">
        <!--li data-filter="*"><a href="#">todos</a></li>-->
        <li class="active" data-filter=".teste1"><a href="#"> teste1</a></li>
        <li data-filter=".teste2"><a href="#">teste2</a></li>
        <li data-filter=".teste3"><a href="#">teste3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row portfolio_inner">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 teste1">
        teste 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 teste2">
        teste 2
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 teste2 teste3">
        teste 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Respondemos quase ao mesmo tempo.. hahaha

Comment: @fernandosavio é que eu ainda parei para consertar na pergunta primeiro :P

Comment: @LeandroAngelo perfeito, como posso bonificar apenas um, obrigado tbm ao fernando savio..rs detalhes que quando estamos de cabeça cheio nao conseguimos arrumar.....obrigadãoooo

Answer (score 1):

Para retirar o "Todos" você precisa:

1. Remover o HTML dos filtros, ou seja, remover o

   ```
   <li class="active" data-filter="*"><a href="#">todos</a></li>
   ```
2. Definir o filtro inicial no construtor do *isotope*

   ```
   $(".portfolio_inner").isotope({
       layoutMode: 'fitRows',  
       filter: '.teste1'  // adicionar esta linha
   });
   ```

Exemplo do seu código funcionando:

```js
//* Isotope js
    function protfolioIsotope(){
        if ( $('.portfolio').length ){ 
            // Activate isotope in container
            $(".portfolio_inner").imagesLoaded( function() {
                $(".portfolio_inner").isotope({
                    layoutMode: 'fitRows',  
                    filter: '.teste1'  // <--- filtro inicial
                }); 
            }); 
            
            // Add isotope click function 
            $(".portfolio_filter li").on('click',function(){
                $(".portfolio_filter li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active"); 
                // element.removeAttribute('data-filter');  // <--- linha removida
                var selector = $(this).attr("data-filter");
                $(".portfolio_inner").isotope({
                    filter: selector,
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 450,
                        easing: "linear",
                        queue: false,
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }); 
             
            //*  Simple LightBox js 
            $('.imageGallery .light').simpleLightbox()
        };
    };

    protfolioIsotope();
```

```css
@import 'https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import 'https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/css/font-awesome.min.css';
@import 'https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/css/style.css';
```

```html
<!-- jQuery v3.3.1 -->
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap v4.0.0 -->
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/vendors/parallaxmouse/parallax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/vendors/lightbox/simpleLightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/vendors/isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.quattropublicidades.com.br/starck/vendors/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<section class="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 class="col-xl-3 tittle">Meus Trabalhos</h2>
      <ul class="portfolio_filter col-xl-9">
        <!-- <li class="active" data-filter="*"><a href="#">todos</a></li> <-- linha removida -->
        <li data-filter=".teste1" class="active"><a href="#"> teste1</a></li>
        <li data-filter=".teste2"><a href="#">teste2</a></li>
        <li data-filter=".teste3"><a href="#">teste3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row portfolio_inner">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 graphic creative project teste1">
        teste 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 graphic creative project teste2">
        teste 2
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 graphic creative project teste3">
        teste 3
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo link que você adicionou em seu comentário que define o que vai estar ativo é a classe ativo (`class="active"`) e o que define quem pertence ao filtro é o código `data-filter=""` sendo * (asterisco) referente a todos,

Basta adicionar a classe active no teste1 e remover o li de mostrar todos:

```
<div class="row">
      <h2 class="col-xl-3 tittle">Meus Trabalhos</h2>
      <ul class="portfolio_filter col-xl-9">
        <li class="active" data-filter=".teste1"><a href="#"> teste1</a></li>
        <li data-filter=".teste2"><a href="#">teste2</a></li>
        <li data-filter=".teste3"><a href="#">teste3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```